# wrong values outputted from enum

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to use the `(char) enum` to store my ranks and then output them using cout but its not getting out correctly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;    

enum rank : char {
    first = '1', second = '2', third = '3'
};

int main()
{
    // other code ...
    cout << rank::third;
    // other code ...
}
```

It outputs `51` !!! look here - http://ideone.com/8vHzQ5

This looks like ascii values(?) so should I caste them back to char or some other type (why do I need to do so when I've already written `char` against that enum), otherwise what is wrong here?

Comment: Yes, cast it back to `char`. `enum` values are `int`s, basically. Same thing as `int n='1'; std::cout << n;`

Comment: You can also create an overload for `std::ostream& operator<<` as seen in the example at the bottom of the reference page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default enum values are treated as `int` in this case. `51` is the decimal ASCII value of `3`; if you want to print `3` you need to cast it explicitly.

```
std::cout << static_cast<char>(rank::third);
```